# Can listoffigures use the long caption instead?

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, captions

Throughout my document I have figures with captions set like this example:

```
\caption[Surface elevation change for Antarctica and Greenland]{Rate of change of surface elevation for Antarctica and Greenland over the period 2003-2007. Source: \citet{pritchard:09}.}
```

My problem is that I would like to change my List of Figures from using the short captions to using the long captions instead. Is there any way to do this with `\listoffigures` without having to change every figure `\caption`?

My shortened working document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\pagestyle{headings} 
\usepackage[top=3.4cm,left=2.2cm,right=3.5cm,bottom=3.0cm]{geometry}     
\geometry{a4paper} 

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} 
\usepackage{natbib} 
\renewcommand\bibname{Reference List}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}


\renewcommand{\topfraction}{.85}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{.7}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{.15}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{.66}
\renewcommand{\dbltopfraction}{.66}
\renewcommand{\dblfloatpagefraction}{.66}

\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{epstopdf} 
\usepackage{rotating}


\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{longtable}

\renewcommand\contentsname{Contents}
\renewcommand\cftpartpresnum{PART }

\usepackage[pdftex,bookmarks=true,hidelinks,bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage{lscape} \linespread{1.6} \DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .tif`.png}


\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{18pt} % space below table caption

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{top=3.4cm,left=3.5cm,right=2cm,bottom=3.0cm}
\include{./title/1_tex/title}
\restoregeometry
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}
\pagenumbering{roman} \setcounter{page}{1}
\include{./declaration/1_tex/declarations}

\begin{spacing}{1.1}

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\phantomsection \label{listoffig}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures

\newpage
\phantomsection \label{listoftab}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables
\end{spacing} 

\bibliographystyle{copernicus}
\newpage
\newgeometry{top=3.4cm,left=3.5cm,right=2cm,bottom=3.0cm}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-10mm}{40pt}   
\setlength{\parindent}{25pt}
\begin{spacing}{1.5}
\pagenumbering{arabic} \setcounter{page}{1}
\include{./chapter1/1_tex/chapter1}
...

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What do you have the short caption for then? You needn't specify it at all, it exists only for LoF. Or do I miss something?

Comment: @tohecz It seems the question is about changing the output of an already written document with lots of captions with optional argument.

Comment: @tohecz Yes, what lockstep has said. The change is an editorial decision. I'm aware I could edit scores of captions, but am wondering if there would be a quicker way of changing the presentation of the LoF.

Comment: note that your citation of `pritchard:09` needs to become `\protect\citet{pritchard:09}` if you're going to make this change.

Comment: @tohecz I've just found this question because, as lockstep suggested, I've got a long document with short captions present, and now it turns out that the department actually *wants* long captions in the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can "revert" the existence of the optional argument by adding this at the end of your preamble:

```
\let\origcaption\caption
\renewcommand\caption[2][]{\origcaption{#2}}
```

Comment: Thanks @tohecz. Does the trick. Between both answers I think I understand how the solution works.

Answer (score 6):

The `caption` package does offer the option `list-entry=heading`for that purpose, at least since v3.3:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[list-entry=heading]{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{test}
\caption[Short caption text]{Full caption text}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

See `endfloat` package documentation for details, section "8.4.1 Removing captions".

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is highly dependent on what class you are using and whether you are using any caption formatting packages, which you have not shown. Please *always* post a complete small document that shows the problem that shows the relevant packages used.

If you are using the standard classes then this changes the toc to use `#3` (the main argument) instead of `#2` (the optional one).

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\@caption#1[#2]#3{%
  \par
  \addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
    %%%%%%{\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
    {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3}}%
  \begingroup
    \@parboxrestore
    \if@minipage
      \@setminipage
    \fi
    \normalsize
    \@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3}\par
  \endgroup}
\makeatother
```