# beamer caption: control line spacing

Tags: beamer, floats

Purpose: control line spacing inside a figure caption ***for the beamer class***.

I can control the font size with:

```
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\scriptsize}
```

**How can I control linespacing?**

Until a few minutes ago I was using the `caption` package with various options. The `caption` package is not recommended with the `beamer` class, which wasn't a problem until a LaTeX package update broke everything (I tried to roll back the update, but did not manage). I would like to do away with the `caption` package  altogether. I used to have this:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\hyper@makecurrent[1]{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{%
  compatibility = {false},% fix for bug in beamer/caption, January 2014
  justification = {justified},
  singlelinecheck = {false},%turns off centering of short captions
  font = {scriptsize,singlespacing},%
  labelfont = {small},%
  labelsep = {space},%
  belowskip=0pt,% skip between caption and surrounding text
  aboveskip=6pt,% skip between table content and caption
  parskip = \baselineskip,% skip between lines
  labelformat = {empty},% 
  figurename = {},%clear labelformat if used
  tablename = {}%clear labelformat if used
}%
```

So to the extent that it is possible, I would like to replicate this output:

[image]

For information, the `caption` package gives the following error message:

```
 Package caption Info: Begin \AtBeginDocument code.
 Package caption Info: End \AtBeginDocument code.
  ! Undefined control sequence.
  <argument> \@@magyar@captionfix 

l.22 \begin{document}
```

I am primarily interested in ***not*** using the `caption` package. I have on several occasions applied patches to fix incompatibility issues, but the latest breakage motivates me to do away with the package (I still use it very happily with the `article` class!).

In addition to `\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\scriptsize}`, I have tried `\setbeamerfont{caption}{size*={8pt}{6pt}}`, but the second argument (6pt) is ignored. I have tried to add `\selectfont{}` and `linespread{0.5}` and a few other things, to no avail.

This is what I get currently. I want much less inter-line spacing.

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames}{xcolor}% named colors
\documentclass[11pt,table,t]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\insertcaption}% removes colon in caption
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\scriptsize}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=0.7\textheight,keepaspectratio]%
{Okies-on-highway-Dorothea-Lange-1938}
\caption{\textbf{Okies:} They were refugees from the Southern Plains farms who migrated to California in the 1930s to escape the Great Depression and the Dust Bowl. This family traveled $124$ miles on foot across Oklahoma. Californians used the term ``Okies'' as an insult and it stuck. Image: Dorothea Lange, ``Family walking on highway, five children'', Works Progress Administration, Library of Congress, June 1938.} 
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must end the paragraph before closing the caption. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48743/164314) for more information. On another note, you can pass options `usenames`, `dvipsnames` and `svgnames` of the `xcolor` package differently (which can be found in Page 19 of the [`beamer`](https://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) documentation).

```
\documentclass[xcolor={usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames},11pt,table,t]{beamer}
% Pass options of `xcolor' like the above
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\insertcaption}% removes colon in caption
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\scriptsize}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\centering
I don't have your picture
\caption{\textbf{Okies:} They were refugees from the Southern Plains farms
    who migrated to California in the 1930s to escape the Great Depression
    and the Dust Bowl. This family traveled $124$ miles on foot across Oklahoma.
    Californians used the term ``Okies'' as an insult and it stuck.
    Image: Dorothea Lange, ``Family walking on highway, five children'',
    Works Progress Administration, Library of Congress, June 1938.\par}% End paragraph
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: line spacing corrected]

Comment: Thank you! It seems so simple. I wonder: can I redefine ``\caption`` to always have a paragraph break at the end? I have dozens of presentations that would be affected, it would be quite tedious to change every file (but yes I know how to do it in bulk). As for the options of the ``xcolor`` package, that's a line I did not intend to include, but your alternative way of including it in the ``documentclass``  is nice. Thanks!

Comment: @PatrickT Unfortunately, `\setbeamerfont{caption}{...}` “forgets” to take care of the paragraph break, which IMHO is by design: Don’t include large chunk of text in a presentation slide. The alternative solution would be using `\usepackage{caption} \captionsetup{font=scriptsize,labelformat=empty}`.

Comment: Thanks. I have a workaround (works so far, but not extensively tested). Feel free to include it to your answer, which I'll accept anyway. Here the workaround: ``\let\origcaption\caption`` and 
``\renewcommand\caption[2][]{\origcaption{#2\par}}``. This I found here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99839/can-listoffigures-use-the-long-caption-instead

Comment: As explained, the ``caption`` package no longer works (I have the latest ``texlive`` for MacOS updated and all, and the MWE above fails), so it's not a solution. But the workaround I give redefines the ``\caption`` command and seems to work well.

Comment: @PatrickT The `caption` solution worked just fine in my TeX distribution (MiKTeX on Windows). You may want to check the update. Can’t say for sure.

Comment: I am too up to date. It's the update that broke everything. I tried to roll it back, but it has made no difference. Anyhow, I'm good with your solution now. Thanks!